# Why to use select() with fork()?

Tags: c, sockets, select, fork

I came across a program (code given below) which implements select() in a scenario where we needed to combine a concurrent TCP echo server and an iterative UDP server into a single server; inorder to multiplex both the TCP and UDP clients.

I am still unable to understand the purpose of using the fork() alongwith select()? And is there any other way to implement the same code only with select().

Edit- From the comments, I understood that fork() DOESN'T have anything to do with IO. And the use of Non-Blocking IO doesn't mean necessarily to use or not to use fork() or select(). But I still can't wrap my head around the use of fork() in the given code.

Code-

```c
// Server program
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define PORT 5000
#define MAXLINE 1024
int max(int x, int y)
{
    if (x > y)
        return x;
    else
        return y;
}
int main()
{
    int listenfd, connfd, udpfd, nready, maxfdp1;
    char buffer[MAXLINE];
    pid_t childpid;
    fd_set rset;
    ssize_t n;
    socklen_t len;
    const int on = 1;
    struct sockaddr_in cliaddr, servaddr;
    char* message = "Hello Client";
    void sig_chld(int);

    /* create listening TCP socket */
    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // binding server addr structure to listenfd
    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    listen(listenfd, 10);

    /* create UDP socket */
    udpfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    // binding server addr structure to udp sockfd
    bind(udpfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    // clear the descriptor set
    FD_ZERO(&rset);

    // get maxfd
    maxfdp1 = max(listenfd, udpfd) + 1;
    for (;;) {

        // set listenfd and udpfd in readset
        FD_SET(listenfd, &rset);
        FD_SET(udpfd, &rset);

        // select the ready descriptor
        nready = select(maxfdp1, &rset, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        // if tcp socket is readable then handle
        // it by accepting the connection
        if (FD_ISSET(listenfd, &rset)) {
            len = sizeof(cliaddr);
            connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr, &len);
            if ((childpid = fork()) == 0) {
                close(listenfd);
                bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                printf("Message From TCP client: ");
                read(connfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                puts(buffer);
                write(connfd, (const char*)message, sizeof(buffer));
                close(connfd);
                exit(0);
            }
            close(connfd);
        }
        // if udp socket is readable receive the message.
        if (FD_ISSET(udpfd, &rset)) {
            len = sizeof(cliaddr);
            bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            printf("\nMessage from UDP client: ");
            n = recvfrom(udpfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0,
                        (struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr, &len);
            puts(buffer);
            sendto(udpfd, (const char*)message, sizeof(buffer), 0,
                (struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, we will not be looking at your images of code.  Any code you want us to consider should appear *as formatted text* in the question itself.

Comment: It is absolutely false that `fork()` is specific to scenarios with non-blocking I/O.  Quite the contrary.  Using non-blocking I/O is among the ways to handle multiple clients in a single thread (of a single process), so that you don't need to `fork()`.  On the other hand, that you are using non-blocking I/O doesn't necessarily mean that you *sheuldn't* fork, or that you *should* use `select()`, nor are those alternatives mutually exclusive.

Comment: `fork()` creates a new process. Nothing specifically to do with i/o.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: I am sorry for asking the question with a bad formating. I am taking it down and make a new post for the question.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I have edited the post. Please review it now.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  I have edited the post. Please review it now.

Comment: @Shawn I have edited the post. Please review it now.

Comment: Sorry for providing the images instead of the formatted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am still unable to understand the purpose of using the fork() alongwith select()?

`select` is only used here to manage the TCP listening socket and the UDP socket together. It is assumed here that

- if the TCP listening socket is readable then a new client can be accepted, i.e. the `accept` will not block. It is also (wrongly) assumed that `accept` might not fail and will always return a new file descriptor.
- if the UDP socket is readable then a message can be read from the socket, i.e. the `recvfrom` will not block
- that one can write a message to the UDP socket w/o checking that the socket is writable, i.e. the `sendto` will not block

The handling of the accepted TCP client is done within a child process in order to keep the code simpler - that's why the `fork`.

> And is there any other way to implement the same code only with select().

Yes, but it is more complex. If done properly it has to deal with the case of multiple established client connections at the same time, with TCP possibly blocking on write etc.

Comment: Also, what's the purpose of- `void sig_chld(int);` . From what I can understand that this is handler function for SIGCHLD signal. But I can't tell how this is useful to the code.

Comment: @noobie: This is an unrelated question, please don't ask new questions in a comment. But in short: within the code shown this is not used at all.